# Find the value of the constant k on a certain pdf

Tags: probability, self-learning

I'm trying to understand a problem that ask for the following:

Given a random variable $X$ that has a pdf $f(x)= k(1-x)^{\frac1\theta-1}$, for x between 0 and 1, find the value of $k$ in function of θ (i'm translating from spanish, I hope it's like this). $\theta$ is a distribution parameter that's always larger than $0$.

I don't understand what the question is asking me to do, ¿could you help me see what I need to do, or maybe show me the first steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use one property of a probability density function. The integral between $0$ and $1$ must be $1$, since $f(x)=0$ for $x<0,x>1$.

See [here](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/legitimate-probability-density-functions#hid2) for the properties of a probability density function.

$$k\cdot \int_0^1 (1-x)^{\frac1\theta-1}  \, dx=1$$

We can substitute $\frac1\theta-1$ by constant $c$

$$k\cdot \int_0^1 (1-x)^c  \, dx=1$$

And the antiderivative of $(1-x)^c$ is

$-\frac{1}{c+1}\cdot (1-x)^{c+1}$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I think so. After integrating, i'm left with $k(-\frac{1}{c+1})=1$, which should lead to $k=-\frac{1}{\theta}$

Comment: Almost. If we inssert the limits we get $-\frac{1}{c+1}\cdot (1-1)^{c+1}\color{red} -[\color{red} -\frac{1}{c+1}\cdot (1-0)^{c+1}] =0+\frac1{c+1}=\frac1{c+1}$. Thus $k\cdot \frac{1}{c+1}=1$. It seems that you haven´t took into account the double minus signs in the calculation (red marked).

Answer (score 0):

You have to find $k$ such that $f$ is a pdf. In fact, you have to choose $k$ such that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x)dx =1$. Hence, $\displaystyle k = \dfrac{1}{\int_0^1 (1-x)^{\frac{1}{\theta}-1}dx}$.